# How can I calculate this limit, and is it valid to apply this property?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Assuming that $|\alpha| \neq |\beta|$, calculate this limit:

$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{1}{T}$ $\int_{0}^{T}$ $sin(\alpha x)cos(\beta x) dx$

At firt instance I thought this limit might converge to 0, because $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}$ $\frac{1}{T}=0$.
Nerverthless, I calculated first the integral, and I got this:

$\int_{0}^{T}$ $sin(\alpha x)cos(\beta x) dx=\frac{1}{2(\alpha-\beta)}+\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)}-\frac{cos((\alpha-\beta)T)}{2(\alpha-\beta)}-\frac{cos((\alpha+\beta)T)}{2(\alpha+\beta)}$

So, I have 2 doubts:

- First, how can I calculate the limit of integral result?

$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}$ $\left (\frac{1}{2(\alpha-\beta)}+\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)}-\frac{cos((\alpha-\beta)T)}{2(\alpha-\beta)}-\frac{cos((\alpha+\beta)T)}{2(\alpha+\beta)}\right )$

- Second, once I've already calculated that limit, is it valid to apply this?

  $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}$$\frac{1}{T}$$\cdot$$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}$$\int_{0}^{T}$ $sin(\alpha x)cos(\beta x) dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $2 \sin (\alpha x) \cos (\beta x)=\sin ((\alpha+\beta )x) +\sin ((\alpha-\beta )x)$. You can compute the integrals for the two terms explicitly. The answer is $0$.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I used that hint to calculate the integral. Neverthless, I still don't know how can I obtain the result of the result of the integral. This is   $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}$ $\left (\frac{1}{2(\alpha-\beta)}+\frac{1}{2(\alpha+\beta)}-\frac{cos((\alpha-\beta)T)}{2(\alpha-\beta)}-\frac{cos((\alpha+\beta)T)}{2(\alpha+\beta)}\right )$

Comment: @luisegf You forgot to divide by $T$ before taking the limit. Since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are boouded functions the limit is $0+0+0+0=0$.